# Should All Parameters In A Prepared Statement Always Use Placeholders?

Tags: sql-server, prepared-statement

I have been attempting to find something that tells me one way or the other on how to write a prepared statement when a parameter is static.
Should all parameters always use placeholders, even when the value is always the same?

     `SELECT *
     FROM student
     WHERE admission_status = 'Pending' AND
        gpa BETWEEN ? AND ?`

ie, in this example admission_status will never be anything but 'Pending', but gpa will change depending on either user input or different method calls.

I know this isn't the best example, but the reason I ask is that I have found a noticeable difference in execution speed when replacing all static parameters that where using a placeholder with their static value counterpart in queries that are hundreds of lines long.

Is it acceptable to do this?  Or does this go against the standards of prepared statement use?  I would like to know one way or the other before I begin to "optimize" larger queries by testing new indexes and replacing the ?s with values to see if there is a boost in execution speed.

Comment: `'Pending'` is only explicitly a parameter if you make it one, so your question begs the question. SQL Server has a feature known as autoparameterization/parameter sniffing where, for some forms of query, constants like `'Pending'` are automatically turned into parameters with queries rewritten (so future queries that use `admission_status = 'Completed'`) would also match the same execution plan). This can be a boon to applications that under-parameterize, or a problem for applications that actually want different plans because the efficient approach for both values radically differs.

Comment: All this is a long and complicated way of saying: you should, in general, not turn constants into parameters just because you can imagine a different value, because the optimizer can generate better plans with known values (although it *might* not, due to parameter sniffing). Use parameters only if you actually have need to change the value. In cases where this produces worse results, there are well-documented options for circumventing or mitigating parameter sniffing. Do not, as a matter of course, start replacing parameters as strings to speed things up -- SQL injection is a real risk.